# Hyperlink on bars in ChartJS in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-chartjs, react-functional-component

I am using **chartjs-2** in react functional component (please find the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-brook-okkce?file=/src/Dashboard.jsx)

I have rendered 4 bars here and I want to have a specific handler function defined for onClick event on each bar.
Like there are 4 types in the bar labels and on clicking on each bar I want to display something specific to the type of the bar clicked.
How to implement this?

```
function Dashboard(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setdata] = React.useState({
    labels: ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "text that comes on hover", 
        backgroundColor: [
          //................................................colors of the bars............
          "#3e95cd",
          "#8e5ea2",
          "#3cba9f",
          "#e8c3b9",
          "#c45850"
        ],
        barThickness: 80,
        data: [50, 100, 75, 20, 0] //......................values for each bar...........
      }
    ]
  });

  const getChartData = canvas => {
    return data;
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        className={classes.chart}
        style={{ position: "relative", width: 900, height: 450 }}
      >
        <Bar
          options={{
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            legend: { display: false },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Title for the graph"
            }
          }}
          data={getChartData}
        />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onElementsClick`. Please check the below code:

```
<Bar
    options={{
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        legend: {display: false},
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Title for the graph"
        }
    }}
    onElementsClick={(e) => {
        console.log(e, 'e')
    }}
    data={getChartData}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked really well, to get the type associated with the bar I used, `console.log(e[0]._model.label, "e");`

Comment: There's one issue if the value of the bar is 0, it doesn't show anything (understood it is zero) but it's now showing 0 on hover also onclick it throws error that "_model.label" undefined. Any suggestion to show some bar even at 0 value?

Comment: if the value is zero then no bar will be shown then how and where you click. actually I did not understand what is the exact issue. can please share some example?

Comment: yeah exactly if there is no bar how can it trigger onClick and error, but it did happen even when there was no bar still clicking on that area triggered the ._model.label method and error was there. Later I did some styling to show the bar even at 0, it's fine now, no error on clicking.

Comment: oh great, you could fix it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-brook-okkce?file=/src/Dashboard.jsx you may check the changes if needed :) (but clicking on bar with 0 value doesn't show anything in console since it's value is undefined)